# Items and tags and set membership

Tags: sql

I apologise in advance for the necessarily vague nature of this question.

I'm trying to "track down" a question and I hope that I can get some help here - there was a part of the answer that I didn't quite grasp and I wanted to pursue it, but I've lost the post.

It was to do with `items` and `tags`.

The OP's question was about items and tags and a set (say (1, 2, 3).

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE stuff 
(
  item TEXT, -- or maybe CHAR(1) or equivalent
  tag INT
); 

INSERT INTO stuff VALUES ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('x', 1), ('x', 2), ('s', 1), ('s', 1), ('s', 2), ('s', 3), ('s', 4);
```

What the OP wanted is a query that matches 3 and exactly 3 tags in the set (1, 2, 3) so the result should be only 'a'.

The correct answer was something along the lines of `SELECT fields.... maybe a subquery?` and then `WHERE` or `HAVING` match at least 3 items and then `MIN(something) = 3)` match only 3...

I've tried searching through a pile of posts both on DBA.SE and SO but just can't seem to find it. I'd be very grateful if this question triggers somebody's memory or they can suggest a search strategy.

I did comment on the OP's question twice but then deleted those comments. Is there any way a moderator can dig those up - I did also search through my comments. TIA for any help in this regard.

Comment: You're looking for `group by`, `having`, and `count distinct`. [Check this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51503826/3094533)

Comment: That's helpful - what search strategy did yo use to search for multiple words within the same post? Is there a way of doing search for "word1" AND "word2" AND "word3" - like performing an SQL style search - short of downloading many posts. I know that the word item (or the plural), tag (not referring to a SO tag, just literally the string 'tag' and 'MIN(' also occurs in the answer. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Since it's a post I've answered myself, I've just searched my own answers and found it....